# angularjs unit tests - mock service inside services

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm testing service A, but service A depends on service B. (eg service B is injected into service A) and service B depends on service C (eg service C is injected into service B).

I have tried mocking service B in service A

```
 describe('Testing ServiceA', function () {
    var serviceA, serviceBMock;           
        beforeEach(function () {                 
            serviceBMock= { 
                    get: function () {
                       return 'mockReturnValue';
                    }
            };
            angular.module('serviceAMocks', [])                  
                .value('ServiceB', serviceBMock);             

        });
         beforeEach(module('serviceAMocks'));
         beforeEach(inject(function (_ServiceA_){
            serviceA=_ServiceA_;
           });

        it('Gets', function () {  
        });
  }
```

I get error:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: serviceC Provider <-  ServiceC <-  ServiceB<- ServiceA

if i remove it block no error if i place it block i get service C dependecy error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like this to make Angular inject your mocked service (Service B) into Service A:

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {

    var serviceBMock= { 
        get: function () {
            return 'mockReturnValue';
        }
    };
    $provide.constant('serviceB', serviceBMock);
}));
```

Comment: I have tried and it worked...and cause of the issue was using  $provide.service.......but i couldn't understand why we need to use  $provide.constant and not  $provide.service???

Comment: @EnugulaS I think the explanation can be gleaned from [this page of the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). Can't say it with certainty, but using `constant()` is a way to create services in Angular's "configuration" phase. So you are in effect, beating Angular to the punch and creating your mock service before it normally would be created.